# rpyc, how to handle disconnect and reconnect

Tags: python-3.x, rpyc

using w10/64, python 3.6, rpyc
I have a server receiving serial data and want the data to be published to any client asking for a connection.
In the server I add every client into a connection list and when detecting changes in the data publish it to all clients.
Clients send a "startListening" request to the server including ip and port. The server then opens its own connection to the client to update it with the new data.
I have an "on_disconnect" method in my servers commands class and it gets triggered when a client stops.
When the client restarts and sends a "startListening" again I get an EOFError on the server showing the clients ip/port.
How can I properly detect and close the client connection to allow for a reconnect?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no built-in mechanism to reconnect, you can implement this functionality as a wrapper around your RPyC `Service` connector. For the sake of example, let's make a "database" that you will connect to over RPyC:

```py
class Database:

    def exposed_keep_alive(self) -> None:
        """
        Does nothing, just ensures that the connection is still alive.
        """
```

The client side will connect to the server side database, but will then wrap the connector to check if the connection has been lost. In this case, it will try to reconnect:

```py
class DatabaseConnector:
    def __init__(self):
        self._connect()

    def _connect(self):
        self._db = rpyc.connect(HOST, PORT).root

    ...

    @property
    def db(self):
        try:
            self._db.exposed_keep_alive()
        except EOFError:
            self._connect()
            return self.db
    
        return self._db
```

Now, you can easily use the `.db` property to "access the database", and if there are any disconnects, it will automatically try and reconnect. Although this isn't perfect code, I think it gets the point across on how to wrap RPyC to implement the reconnection functionality you're seeking.